# Cut slab smooth?

Tags: modeling, mesh

This is a very basic matter, and I have searched for a solution for some time but wasn't able to find anything that worked the way I wanted.

I have a mesh that looks like this:

[image]

Basically what I want is to match the gradient of the middle part to that of the lower part. For example by removing this area:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a decent way to achieve this? I feel like there is some tool that is exactly fit for this kind of operation, but I don't know how to use it or where to find it.

[image].

Comment: I'm not 100% on the math part of it, but you can enable "face angle", "edge length" and "edge angle" under viewport overlays, that will show you some more numbers you can work with. It might help you with solving the Pythagorean theorem despite the top part of the triangle missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping <kbd>C</kbd> while using the <kbd>K</kbd> knife tool will constrain it to 45 degree increments with respect to the view, and in this case, we can align the view to the desired cut.

- Select the face you want the cut to be aligned to, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, depending on your working object-axis.

[image]

- Now the view is looking straight across the face, you can use
  <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> to constrain, and <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut
  through, to make the cut as shown above.
- After making the cut, and returning to a less disorienting view, you can either <kbd>X</kbd> delete the excess faces, and <kbd>F</kbd> fill the hole, or <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the protruding edge all the way to the cut, and <kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance* merge the then coincident vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much! Aligning a face to an axis with Shift Numpad 1 was exactly what I needed!